# Godot 3.2 atlasTexture not creating any texture atlas

Tags: textures, godot, texture-atlas, import, gdscript

When I try to use the new feature of godot that lets you import sprites as an atlasTexture, I dont' get any results. [image]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem while I did everthing listed on this page: https://godotengine.org/article/atlas-support-returns-godot-3-2 I don't know it is my fault or the engine but since I find you have the same problem, which makes me think maybe it's the latter.

Comment: I'm also having this issue.